# Power a large number with a large number then mode the result

Tags: c#

I need to compute `r = g`<sup>`k`</sup>`mod p` where both `g` and `k` could be large integer, I mean they could be 64 bit integer. Is there any way?

Comment: Reduce `g mod p`, `k mod phi(p)`, then use something like square and multiply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the [BigInteger.ModPow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) can represent arbitrarily large integer values.

> The ModPow method evaluates the following expression:
>   (baseValue ^ exponent) Mod modulus

Example from MSDN:

```
BigInteger number = 10;
int exponent = 3;
BigInteger modulus = 30;
Console.WriteLine("({0}^{1}) Mod {2} = {3}", 
                  number, exponent, modulus, 
                  BigInteger.ModPow(number, exponent, modulus));   
//Result: (10^3) Mod 30 = 10
```

If you don't want to use that one but instead implement the operation yourself, there are certain [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) that can be used to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would prefer to stay with integers you can also implement your own `ModularPower` method:

```
    public static int ModularPower(int baseVal, int expVal, int modVal)
    {
        int initialVal = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < expVal; ++i)
        {
            initialVal = (initialVal * baseVal) % modVal;
        }

        return initialVal;
    }
```

Details of the algorithm and a pseudo code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).